# C# Test Coverage is empty in SonarQube Dashboard

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, sonarqube, code-coverage

I have configured SonarQube locally. I was able to Scan and build my C# project successfully. In the SonarQube dashboard, all the metrics are getting displayed correctly but the Test coverage is not showing up and that metric is empty.

In this WPF project. We have test cases written in xunit, nunit and mstest.

My project structure looks likes this.

```
.sonarqube
packages
abcompany.Xyz.Tests
abcompany.Xyz.Api
abcompany.Xyz.Api.Tests
abcompany.Xyz.Api.Tool
abcompany.Xyz.Api.Tool.Tests
abcompany.Xyz.Common
abcompany.Xyz.Common.Tests
abcompany.Xyz.Service
abcompany.Xyz.Service.Tests
abcompany.Xyz.Service
abcompany.Xyz.UI
abcompany.Xyz.UI.Tests
abcompany.Xyz.UI.Common
SonarQube.ps
abcompany.Xyz.sln
```

In SonarQube.ps I have,

```
SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"abcompany-proj" /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000" 
/d:sonar.login="---token---" 

MsBuild.exe  /t:Rebuild

SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end /d:sonar.login="---token---"
```

1. Do I explicitly need mention some parameters to build or run test projects to get the coverage?
2. If so, what are the parameters that I'm missing ?
3. Can MSBuild alone do the test coverage or do I need to use a 3rd party to generate the coverage.xml (for example using Open Cover or Visual Studio Code Coverage). In Java they use Jacoco for this.
4. Can we use Jacoco for C# test coverage?

Thanks in advance and Can anyone guide me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You specify where the `reportsPath` and `vscoveragexml.reportsPaths`.  For MSTest, this would look like this:

```
/d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths="{somePath}.trx" /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths="{someOtherPath}.coveragexml"
```

[SonarQube Documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/) also list for nunit and xunit the following `reportPath` parameters:

- `sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths`
- `sonar.cs.xunit.reportsPaths`

Note that these parameters support the use of wildcards.

Between your SonarQube `begin` and `end` calls, you will need to run the tests.   You can use ["VSTest.Console.Exe"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2022) (you may need to add this your system PATH).

You can read the documentation of this executable via that link, but an example command line may look like:

```
vstest.console /Parallel /EnableCodeCoverage /Logger:trx TestSuiteOne.dll TestSuiteTwo.dll TestSuiteThree.dll
```

This should run all your tests and produce `.coverage` files.  From my experience, these then need to be converted into `.coverage.coveragexml` for SonarQube to be able to interpret them. You can use the CodeCoverage.exe to do this (I believe this may only be available for Visual Studio Enterprise out of the box, but I think you can also use [Microsoft.TestPlatform](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TestPlatform/)). Using the CodeCoverage.exe, the command line may look like:

```
"{pathToExe}/CodeCoverage.exe" analyze /output: "{outputFilePath}/SomeName.coveragexml" "{pathToCoverageFile}/SomeOtherName.coverage"
```

As for Jacoco, that only seems to be for Java from what I can tell looking at [their website](https://www.eclemma.org/index.html).